# Why does apply convert logicals in data frames to strings of 5 characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
mydf <- data.frame(colA = c(1,20), colB = c("a", "ab"), colC = c(T, F))
```

Now suppose I want to apply a function to each row on the data frame. This function uses the boolean value of column C. When using `apply`, every non-string is converted to a string of the maximum length present in the column:

```
> apply(mydf, 1, '[', 3)
[1] " TRUE" "FALSE"
```

The string `" TRUE"` is no longer interpretable as a logical.

```
> ifelse(apply(mydf, 1, '[', 3), 1, 2)
[1] NA  2
```

I could solve this with a `gsub(" ", "", x)`, but I'd bet there is a better way. Why does `apply` have this behavior when it could just directly convert the logicals to strings? Is there an `apply`-like function which does not have the above behavior?

Comment: Indeed. Is there an `apply`-like function without this behavior?

Comment: look into the package plyr, which is a wrapper for the base apply functions.  You can get around these coercion effects with plyr methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you called `apply`, your data frame was converted to a character matrix.   The spaces appear because each element is converted to the width of the widest element in the column.

You can do it with a `for` loop-like `sapply` call

```
> ( s <- sapply(seq(nrow(mydf)), function(i) mydf[i, 3]) )
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
> class(s)
# [1] "logical"
```

A workaround to what you are doing with `apply` would be

```
> as.logical(gsub("\\s+", "", apply(mydf, 1, `[`, 3)))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

But note that these are both exactly the same as

```
> mydf[,3]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Looks like `sapply` will be the way to go. I'll go with `sapply(seq(nrow(mydf)), function(i) myfun(mydf[i, ]))`, where `myfun` is my function that acts on a row. Though I may just write a function that does this automatically so I can have the familiar `apply` syntax and not have to write that out each time.

Answer (score 4):

`apply` does not work directly with data.frames; it works with matrices and with matrices all elements must be the same atomic type. If you pass in a data.frame, `apply()` will coerce it to a matrix. Since character values can't be stored in a more "simple" datatype, everything is converted up to a character value.

Normally you don't have think about applying functions to rows of a data.frame one a time. Most of the time what you want to accomplish can be done using the basic vectored functions across the columns of a data.frame. If you wanted

```
ifelse(apply(mydf, 1, '[', 3), 1, 2)
```

try

```
ifelse(mydf[, 3], 1, 2)
```

instead