# 'non-numeric argument to binary operator' when running apply() on dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame like below:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
coef_ind <- c(0.5,0.6,1,2)
type <- c("power","power","expo","expo")
tf <- data.frame(x=x,coef_ind=coef_ind,type=type)

> tf
  x coef_ind  type
1 1      0.5 power
2 2      0.6 power
3 3      1.0  expo
4 4      2.0  expo
```

and I have wrote a function like below:

```
cal <- function(df){
  
  x = df['x']
  type = df['type']
  coef = df['coef_ind']
  
  if(type == "power"){
    outcome = x^coef
  }
  
  if(type == "expo"){
    outcome = 1- exp(- coef*x)
  }
  return(outcome)
}
```

Now, I want to apply the function to each table row. Thus:

```
apply(tf,1,cal)
```

However, I get the error hint

```
Error in x^coef : non-numeric argument to binary operator
enter code here
```

Could you please share your knowledge concerning this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: oddly, `apply` is turning each row into a vector of strings before running cal. Unsure why though

Comment: ahh this is it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854241/4145280

Comment: you probably want something like this: `tf |>
  dplyr::mutate(outcome = case_when(
    type == "power" ~ x^coef_ind,
    type == "expo" ~ 1- exp(- coef_ind*x)
  ))`

Comment: R is [vectorized](https://docs.ycrc.yale.edu/r-novice-gapminder/09-vectorization/), so in this case you dont need `apply` - you can simply do `df$cal <- ifelse(df$type == "power", df$x ^ df$coef_ind, 1 - exp(-df$coef_ind * df$x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `apply` casts to matrix, every value needs to be of the same type. If there's a string or character column present, everything gets cast to strings.
You can still use your function by forcing the numerical values back to numeric.

```
cal <- function(df){
  
  x = as.numeric(df['x'])
  type = df['type']
  coef = as.numeric(df['coef_ind'])
  
  if(type == "power"){
    outcome = x^coef
  }
  
  if(type == "expo"){
    outcome = 1- exp(- coef*x)
  }
  return(outcome)
}
```

```
apply(tf, 1, cal)
[1] 1.0000000 1.5157166 0.9502129 0.9996645
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, to quote [Mr. Flick's answer from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854241/4145280):

> `apply` does not work directly with data.frames; it works with matrices and with matrices all elements must be the same atomic type. If you pass in a data.frame, `apply()` will coerce it to a matrix. Since character values can't be stored in a more "simple" datatype, ***everything is converted up to a character value***.

So the issue is that, for the first row, for example, your function isn't getting the argument `c(1, 0.5, "power")`, it's getting `c("1", "0.5", "power"`, which is failing on the line `outcome = x^coef`, because the first two arguments are no longer numbers - they're strings.

One easy alternative is using `dplyr`:

```
tf |>
  mutate(outcome = case_when(
    type == "power" ~ x^coef_ind,
    type == "expo" ~ 1- exp(- coef_ind*x)
  ))

# Output
  x coef_ind  type   outcome
1 1      0.5 power 1.0000000
2 2      0.6 power 1.5157166
3 3      1.0  expo 0.9502129
4 4      2.0  expo 0.9996645
```

Comment: Hi, Mark. Thanks for your informative response and for kindly proposing a solution. It definitely works for the example I provided, but my real project is a bit more complicated (more advanced calculation) which makes it uneasy to list all combinations in case_when (or ifelse). Andre below provides another solution which works better for my case, which may be a good reference for you too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since, your operations can run on whole columns (i.e., atomic vectors), consider vectorizing your process with a nested `ifelse`. Vectorization runs more efficient than iteration with `for` or `apply` loops across rows or columns. With base R consider `within` to conditionally add new *outcome* column inside a data frame context.

```r
df <- within(
  df, {
      outcome <- ifelse(
          type == "power", x^coeff, ifelse(
              type == "expo", 1- exp(- coef*x), NA
          )
      )       
  }
)
```